# Designing database for a (Post) entity that has another entity as an author between many other entities

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, erd

I'm trying to design a relational database ERD where I have a post that can be written by either a student or a teacher, but not both.
I have done something like in this pictures

Conceptual Data Model:
[Conceptual Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fglWM.png)

Physical Data Model:
[Physical Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxM70.png)

I can leave it like that and give one of the foreign keys a value and leave the other null. But that doesn't restrict that both the foreign keys can't have a value at the same time.

Is there a good design solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure what your other requirements are, but if you combined students and teachers into a single table, perhaps with an ENUM column to differentiate the two when it matters, then you would need only one foreign key on the Post table.

Comment: FKs cannot be used for non-trivial constraints.